# «Ребенок войны» — нужны ли кавычки?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, названия

Ребенок войны. Нужны ли кавычки? Речь о статусе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дети войны, ребенок войны, сын полка, ветеран войны, бывший малолетний узник фашистских концлагерей, житель блокадного Ленинграда — эти категории людей ("категории" — недоброе какое-то слово) всем известны.

Я вижу здесь три возможности.

Если мы знаем, что человек родился в период с 22 июня 1928 года по 4 сентября 1945-го и просто констатируем этот факт, то кавычки не нужны.
*В пояснительной записке приводятся данные Минтруда, согласно которым в России сегодня насчитывается порядка 13 миллионов **детей войны.***

Если мы используем слово "статус" вместе со словосочетанием в падеже (то есть согласуем его), то кавычки не нужны.
Получить статус (кого?) ребенка войны, детей войны.
*Законопроектом предлагается установить ежемесячную выплату в размере 1000 рублей всем россиянам **со статусом детей войны**...*

Если же мы используем слово "статус" в качестве родового слова и словосочетание употребляем в именительном падеже (как название), то кавычки необходимы.
Получить статус «ребенок войны».
*Автор указывает, что отсутствие чёткой законодательной базы федерального уровня о присвоении **статуса «дети войны»** создаёт неравные условия для граждан, проживающих в разных регионах страны.*

[В Госдуму внесли законопроект о льготах детям войны](https://www.pnp.ru/social/v-gosdumu-vnesli-zakonoproekt-o-lgotakh-detyam-voyny.html) («Парламентская газета»)